# How to get Websphere to prompt for a database JNDI connection

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, websphere, jndi, websphere-9

I have an EAR application, containing an EJB and a WAR.

In the EJB I am using JPA to connect to the database, and then the WAR deals with the REST endpoints and calls methods defined in the EJB:

e.g - EJB Stateless Bean:

```java
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

and EJB persistence.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="WOTISEJB">
        <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/appds</jta-data-source>
        <class>com...</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Web class:

```java
@Path("/getByType")
@ManagedBean
public class GetByTypeResource 
{
    @EJB
    EjbDao ejbDao;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getData(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @PathParam("type") Type type)
    {
        JsonObject response = ejbDao.getByType(type);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        try (JsonWriter jw = Json.createWriter(sw)) {
            jw.write(response);
        }
        String retVal = sw.toString();
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

I presume I don't need anything in my web.xml as all of the EntityManager definitions are in the EJB code (and just called from the WEB application) - but just in case it's relevant:

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appname</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.app.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appname</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <display-name>App Name</display-name>
</web-app>
```

When I install the application onto Websphere 9.0.5, I was expecting to be prompted as part of the installation to map the jndi name `java:comp/env/jdbc/appds` to the JDBC datasource I have already created in the console; however it is just using the default datasource in WAS instead.

What configuration elements am I missing to get the installation process to prompt me for the DSN mapping? In order words I don't want to put the jbdc name directly in the config, but have an indirect lookup which is configured on deploy.

Additionally, am I missing any configuration in my web.xml so that it also knows about the DSN when it calls the methods on the EJB classes, or will that happen automatically?

Comment: You ask if you are missing config in your web.xml but you haven't shared your web.xml. Based on what you provided the issue is you do not have a Resource Reference, but that could be in your web.xml

Comment: @Alasdair added web.xml